# How do I extract Source Engine .vpk files?

Tags: source-engine

I'd like to use some Source Engine models and sounds, so I looked up how to extract them. Most methods say to use GCFScape, which I can use to browse and extract .gcf files. However, since the SteamPipe update, the .gcf files have been replaced with .vpk files.

Is there a way to extract the .vpk files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it's included with the game itself. (This method was tested on Windows using Team Fortress 2.)

- Go to the folder Steam is held in. This varies depending on your OS.
- Next, go to the `steamapps/<username>/<game_here>/` folder. I will be using Team Fortress 2 (under the `team fortress 2` folder.)

  - might also be called "common" instead of your username.
- Under the `tf` folder (or hl2 for Half-Life 2/Portal), find the file ending in `_dir.vpk`. I'm using `tf2_sound_vo_dir.vpk` (the characters' voices), but any .vpk file will work.
- Drag all of the .vpks onto the "vpk.exe" file. You should do this with two windows to make things easier.
- Once this finishes, go to a folder named `tf2_sound_vo_dir` in `bin/` (the folder where vpk.exe is stored).
- Inside is a bunch of folders. Those are the files that were inside the .vpk.
- To compile into a `.vpk`, drag a folder filled with your files (for example, `test_vpk`) down to `vpk.exe`. This should compile into a file named `test_vpk.vpk`.

If this is wrong, or you have a method for another OS, either edit it or leave a comment.